# uninitialized urandom read error appearing in dmesg

Tags: 18.04, kernel, lvm, udev

I'm using:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 4.15.0-72-generic

After the machine finishes to boot, I run into the following errors in the kernel log by running `dmesg`:

```
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x99/0x4fdwith crng_init=0
[    2.185869] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    2.204448] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (2 bytes read)
[    3.938196] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    3.957758] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    4.202035] random: fast init done
[    4.285680] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    6.158973] random: crng init done
[    6.159019] random: 5 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
```

I have installed `haveged` and `rng-tools` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install haveged
sudo apt-get install rng-tools
```

to try and resolve this issue, but it did not help.
Those errors repeat themselves every half an hour or so.
I found this [archlinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249430), but I didn't understand what is needed to be done.

Should I be worried about those errors?
And does anyone have an idea how to make them go away?

Comment: Did you enabled `haveged` via `# systemctl enable haveged`?

Comment: After installation service is enabled by default